# Is it possible to influence the "developer image" presented in AppStore?

Tags: ios, app-store

When searching the AppStore for apps, you sometimes get presented with a card showing the "Developer" instead of an actual app. It looks like this:
[image: Developer pictures]
This picture seems automatically generated. For companies with several apps, is there any way to influence or affect which apps are "centered" in this image? I can't find any information about this image.

Comment: I'm trying to get that image so I can add use it elsewhere. Any ideas?